# API for updating user role using a id - Node

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, crud

I am trying to create a node API and test it using Postman but I keep running into errors. I can't seem to get to update the userRole of my user table. I have tried console.log(req.body.userRole) to print the incoming field I want to update the user role but it is coming up as undefined or throwing an error relating to my Cors settings / unhandledPromiseRejection error when I remove the try catch loop.

In the code below I get a message that it is updated but nothing happens to the value of the table. The userRole is the 7th column of my table and it is spelt correctly. There is a foreign key attached to the userRole table that i'm not sure is causing the error.

It is likely an error in the code as i haven't many update functions working correctly yet.

[image]

```
exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {

    try{
        const userID = req.params.userId;
        //const role = req.body.userRole;
        const user = await User.findByPk(userID);
        //console.log("userRole", req.body.userRole)
        if(!user){
            // return a response to client
            res.status(404).json({
                message: "Not Found for updating a user with id = " + user,
                user: "",
                error: "404"
            });
        } else {
            console.log("userRole", req.body.userRole)
            // update new change to database
            let updatedUser = {
                userID: userID,
                //userRole: role
            }
            let userRes = user.update(updatedUser, {
                returning: true,
                where: {userID: userID}
            });
            // return the response to client
            if(!userRes) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    message: "Error -> Can not update a user with username = " + req.params.userId,
                    error: "Can't Update",
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "Updated role successfully user = " + req.params.userId,
                user: updatedUser,
            });
        }
    } catch(error){
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "Error -> Can not update a customer with userName = " + req.params.userId,
            error: error.message
        });
    }
}
```

model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const userLogin = sequelize.define("userLogins", {

        userID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        userEmail: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        userFirstName: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        userSurname: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        userRole: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        photos: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        }},
        {
        timestamps: false
        })
        userLogin.associate = function(models){
            userLogin.userRole.hasOne(models.userRole, {foreignKey: 'userRoleID', as: 'userRoleID'})
        };
    return userLogin;
};
```

role model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const userRole = sequelize.define("userRoles", {

        userRoleID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        userRoleName: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        }},
        {
            timestamps: false
        },{});
    return userRole;
};
```

Comment: show us your ```user``` and ```role```, ```models``` .

Comment: That's them added now.

Comment: You have a integer field in your model named ```userRole``` but your foreignKey in association is different. Did you define ```userRoleID``` in migration as a reference field?

Comment: I don't have any migrations. Do I definitely need them? I can do posts no problem to the database.

Comment: What should the foreignKey be for integers? I have set a foreign key restraint manually in pgadmin / sequelize already

Comment: If you have a reference field named: ```UserRoleId``` and a model named ```UserRole``` then you don't need to determine foreignKey. Sequelize will understand it.

Comment: So I don't need to do any of the associations at the bottom of my tables if the id fields are the same? what is the advantages of doing migrations? can sequelize do these for me?

Comment: I have just been updating the table and pgadmin manually as I go along. Is that what migrations do?

Comment: You need to read ```sequelize``` documentations and samples. I can't explain all of them here. Migrations will create or update your database and it's structure.
And not related to this question too much. I just asked about that for finding what is ```userRoleID``` and where is it. It is not defined in your model.

Answer (score 0):

example:

- model: User

  fields:

  - Id ( PrimaryKey )
  - RoleId ( Foreign Key )
- model: Role

  fields:

  - Id ( PrimaryKey )

Association in User model is like This (if a user just have a role):

```
      User.belongsTo(models.Role);
```

If you change default scheme then you have to determine it:

- model: User

  fields:

  - Id ( PrimaryKey )
  - i_am_reference_iD ( Foreign Key to Role ID)

```
    User.belongsTo(models.Role, {foreignKey: 'i_am_reference_iD'});
```

Sequelize has a complete documentation. You need to study it to avoid mistakes which they wasting too much time on dev time.

Also you need to clean your codes too.

Comment: Should code be outputting? It might not be a sequelize error. It could just be the code. In terms of doing GET pulls on my front-end should the associations be pulled automatically if I have the field names right? The INT values aren't much use and sounds like a feature Sequelize should have built in. I have Include All in the where part of my API's but nothing other than the table gets pulled.